# Spring security configuration with JWT AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, spring-restcontroller

I get the below error when I try to invoke protected ws using POSTMAN and passing the Authorization header with obtained token after login `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBZGVsSVAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTI2MDM4NTIsImV4cCI6MTU1MjY5MDI1Mn0.OfzkQlhubdLBa9cV7O231M1AB8ya9g5Q1zefhjhPvJIICz45SUunT2xP6r008O-oxUXBQT3RrRha7n6gSo9Jpw`.

Exception :

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
com.spring.jwtauthentication.controller.TestRestAPIs$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11db1a81.adminAccess(&lt;generated&gt;)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please find below my implementation :

1) Login api AuthRestAPIs.java :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthRestAPIs {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser( @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt));
    }

}
```

Test api apiTestRestAPIs.java (protected resource) :

```
@RestController
public class TestRestAPIs {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/api/test//admin")
    public String adminAccess() {
        return ">>> Admin Contents";
    }
}
```

2) Security Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring.jwtauthentication", scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;


    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        JwtAuthTokenFilter test = new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
        return test;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

3) JwtAuthTokenFilter.java :

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
                                            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = getJwt(request);
            if (jwt!=null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

4) JwtProvider.java

```
@Component
public class JwtProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);


    private String jwtSecret = "jwtOlfaSecretKey";

    private int jwtExpiration =86400;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserPrinciple userPrincipal = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                        .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpiration*1000))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                        .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature -> Message: {} ", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                            .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                            .parseClaimsJws(token)
                            .getBody().getSubject();
    }
}
```

5) JwtAuthEntryPoint.java :

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException e) 
                                 throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.error("Unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error -> Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

6) web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>myApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/cfg.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

7) pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: First your JwtAuthTokenFilter is marked @Component but you don't use it, you instead creates a new instance of it. USE IT! with AUTOWIRED!. Also make sure the server is actually receiving the token. Make sure the roles (userdetails.getAuthorities() is NOT NULL). Second thing the purpose of JWT is to be stateless. UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username) piece of code makes it NOT-stateless. If you want/need the authorities, pass it in the JWT token itself as claims in signIn controller using your jwtprovider class. Other parts of your code is ok. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')") instead of @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')"), that would work in your case.